# Error writing cache file

Tags: android

**I'm trying to write to a cache file.**

```
  Uri path1 = Uri.parse("content://package.name/cache");
      File myFile = new File(path1.getPath(),"results.csv");
                final boolean newFile = myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                myOutWriter.append(data);

                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();
```

Added storage permission in Manifest.
Error  I/ExternalStorageDemo: Save to: content://package.name/cache/results.csv W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Comment: check permission granted before this. more details https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: As Shijil said, just adding permission into Manifest is not enough. You have to ask for permission on runtime too. Or just use cache dir.

Comment: `.line 82
    :cond_0
    const-string v9, "content://org.zwanoo.android.speedtest/cache/results.csv"
   >getContentResolver()Landroid/content/ContentResolver;
`    got it when baksmali an app which takes speedtest results from cache. Is it possible to access another app's cache

Answer (score 1):

Use [Context.getCacheDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()) to get applications Internal cache files dirctory

Like This:

`File myFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"results.csv");`

Comment: Is it possible to access another app's cache files

Comment: `.line 82
    :cond_0
    const-string v9, "content://org.zwanoo.android.speedtest/cache/results.csv"
   >getContentResolver()Landroid/content/ContentResolver;
`    got it when baksmali an app which takes speedtest results from cache. Then how does this work

Comment: It's using Content Provider to share it's data to other apps https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html

Answer (score 0):

If your device is working on Android 6 or higher have you already requested runtime permissions?

See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html for more details.

Comment: @NoelSamuel Can you please try this.

Comment: `private boolean askPermission(int requestId, String permissionName) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

       
            int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissionName);


            if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // If don't have permission so prompt the user.
                this.requestPermissions(
                        new String[]{permissionName},
                        requestId
                );
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }`

Comment: Yes thankyou but i didn't get a result as expected so I turned into another approach